# Warning: Illegal string

Tags: php

Hey coders and codettes,

I am wondering if you could help me, I am getting the warning below when trying to execute code

WARNING:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'callsign' in C:\xampp\htdocs\fms\blog.php on line 106
S

This is the Code it refers to:

```
                if($rows1['callsign']=='SN23'OR'SN24'OR'SN25'){
                echo 'IRV';}
                elseif ($rows1['callsign']=='SK20'OR'SK30'){
                echo 'VAN';}
                elseif ($rows1['callsign']=='SN21'OR'SN22'){
                echo 'TASER';}
                elseif ($rows1['callsign']=='C1'OR'C2'){
                echo 'AREA';}
                elseif ($row1['callsign']=='NPAS'){
                echo 'NPAS';} ?>

                <br></font>
                </a>
                </div>
                <center>
                <font color="white">
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#" 
                onclick="popup_viewunit(&#39;105&#39;)">
                <font color="white">
                <h4><b><i class="fa fa-<?php 
                if($rows1['callsign']=='SN23'OR'SN24'OR'SN25'){
                echo 'circle';}
                elseif ($rows1['callsign']=='SK20'OR'SK30'){
                echo 'truck';}
                elseif ($rows1['callsign']=='SN21'OR'SN22'){
                echo 'bolt';}
                elseif ($rows1['callsign']=='C1'OR'C2'){
                echo 'map';}
                elseif ($rows1['callsign']=='NPAS'){
    ROW 106--   echo 'times fa-pulse';} ?>"></i><?php echo 
                $rows1['callsign']; ?></b></h4> -- END  OF ROW 106
                </font>
```

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($rows1['callsign'])){
    echo 'working';
else {
    echo 'Not working';
}
```

My guess would be the value of `$rows1['callsign']` is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

This `($rows1['callsign']=='C1'OR'C2')` does not do what you think it does. It evaluates that statement sort of like:

```
IF ($rows1['callsign'] EQUALS 'C1') OR ('C2' == TRUE) ...
```

You probably want:

```
if($rows1['callsign'] == 'C1' OR $rows1['callsign'] == 'C2') {
```

Also, more than likely that $rows1['callsign'] is not defined, do `print_r($rows1);` and you can see what it actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems here:

1.

```
    $rows1['callsign']=='SK20'OR'SK30'
```

this will not work as you expect, you need to do

```
    $rows1['callsign'] == 'SK20' || $rows1['callsign'] == 'SK30'
```

example:

```
    <?php 
    $a = 3;
    echo (($a == 1 or 2) ? "yes" : "no"); // will output "yes" because "2" will be evaluated to true 
    echo (($a == 1 or $a == 2) ? "yes" : "no"); // correctly outputs "no"
```

2. On one of the lines in the first block you have $row1['callsign'] instead of $rows1['callsign']
3. the error message generally means that $rows1 is not an array. Use var_dump() to see what is actually in it and how it got there